# Testing for NullReferenceException (Not Testing for Nothing)

Tags: .net, null, nullreferenceexception

I have a class someone else wrote for which I don't have the source code. It has a property `UM` that is backed by `_UM`, a string. In some circumstances `_UM` is `Nothing`. I would expect that `UM` would be `Nothing` too, but when I inspect (using Quick Watch) the property it shows as a `NullReferenceException`. When I try testing for `Nothing` I get a `NullReferenceException` thrown in my main code. How can I catch this condition so I can handle it properly?

```
If Foo.UM Is Nothing Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

...throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: The exception may be thrown because `Foo` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Foo isn't nothing. Other properties I can see.

Comment: try  ...  catch NullReferenceException ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property might do more than just return the _UM field. Probably uses it somehow and does not take into account that it might be `null`. You could do something like this to handle it:

```
Dim obj = Nothing
Try
    obj = Foo.UM
Catch ex As NullReferenceException
End Try
If obj Is Nothing Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Comment: I would agree that the property probably does something besides just return `_UM`, however, I don't particularly care. I just need to test and take action. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as it is quite a bit of overhead to process an exception...oh well. This class is quite lousy in other areas, I shouldn't be surprised. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can always decompile the external dll with Reflector for example and see what is actually going on in the property.